# java.lang.NullPointerException al llamar a Service desde clase Listener

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

El error que muestra la consola del servidor es el siguiente:
Éste salta al intentar invocar al método addReportAuditInfo

> [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default
>   task-61) java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.el.ELException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:187)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)     at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>     at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>     at
>   com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminFilter.doFilter(AdminFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>     at
>   io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.minhap.controller.ReportAuditCtrl$1.afterCommit(ReportAuditCtrl.java:42)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:958)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:803)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy633.save(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.minhap.service.UserServiceImpl.addUser(UserServiceImpl.java:21)
>     at
>   com.minhap.controller.UserSelectCtrl.updateUser(UserSelectCtrl.java:118)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
>     ... 121 more

**Clase listener:**

```
package com.minhap.controller;

import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import javax.persistence.PostRemove;
import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;
import com.minhap.model.User;
import com.minhap.service.ReportAuditService;

@Named  
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class ReportAuditCtrl {

    @Autowired
    private ReportAuditService reportAuditService;

    @PostUpdate
    public void onUpdate(Object object) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterCommit() {
                if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    System.out.println("Update User :" + user.getName());
                    ReportAudit reportAudit = new ReportAudit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), "INFO", "Admin", "update in User", "OK", "OK");
//                  try {
//                      reportAuditService.addReportAuditInfo(reportAudit);
//                  } catch (Exception e) {
//                      System.out.println("**** EXCEPTION *** :" + e);
//                  }
                    reportAuditService.addReportAuditInfo(reportAudit);
                }
            }
        });
    }   

    @PostPersist
    public void onPersist(Object object) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterCommit() {
                if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    System.out.println("Insert User :" + user.getName());                   
                }
            }

        });
    }  

    @PostRemove
    public void onRemove(Object object) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterCommit() {
                if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    System.out.println("Remove User :" + user.getName());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ReportAuditService getReportAuditService() {
        return reportAuditService;
    }

    public void setReportAuditService(ReportAuditService reportAuditService) {
        this.reportAuditService = reportAuditService;
    }


}
```

**Clase ServiceImpl**

```
package com.minhap.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.minhap.dao.ReportAuditRepository;
import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;

@Service
public class ReportAuditServiceImpl implements ReportAuditService {

    @Autowired
    private ReportAuditRepository reportAuditRepository;

    @Override
    public ReportAudit addReportAuditInfo(ReportAudit reportAudit) {
        return reportAuditRepository.save(reportAudit);
    }

    public ReportAuditRepository getReportAuditRepository() {
        return reportAuditRepository;
    }

    public void setReportAuditRepository(ReportAuditRepository reportAuditRepository) {
        this.reportAuditRepository = reportAuditRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ReportAudit> getAllReportAudit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ReportAudit getReportAuditById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Interfaz del Service**

```
package com.minhap.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;

public interface ReportAuditService {

    ReportAudit addReportAuditInfo(ReportAudit reportAudit);
    List<ReportAudit>getAllReportAudit();
    ReportAudit getReportAuditById(final Long id);

}
```

**Clase Repository**

```
package com.minhap.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;

@Repository("reportAuditRepository")
public interface ReportAuditRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<ReportAudit, Long> {

}
```

**Bean de Persistencia**

```
    package com.minhap.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Named
@Table(name = "REPORT_AUDIT")
public class ReportAudit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    private Timestamp fx_event;
    private String tipo;
    private String actor;
    private String description;
    private String event_result;
    private String extrainfo;

    public ReportAudit() {
        super();
    }

    public ReportAudit(Timestamp fx_event, String tipo, String actor, String description, String event_result,
            String extrainfo) {
        this.fx_event = fx_event;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.actor = actor;
        this.description = description;
        this.event_result = event_result;
        this.extrainfo = extrainfo;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getFx_event() {
        return fx_event;
    }

    public void setFx_event(Timestamp fx_event) {
        this.fx_event = fx_event;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(String actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEvent_result() {
        return event_result;
    }

    public void setEvent_result(String event_result) {
        this.event_result = event_result;
    }

    public String getExtrainfo() {
        return extrainfo;
    }

    public void setExtrainfo(String extrainfo) {
        this.extrainfo = extrainfo;
    }



}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado!
En las clases "listener" como es mi caso, no basta con hacer **@Autowire** o **@Inject** sobre la propiedad (en este caso Service) para injectar el bean.

Mirando por Internet encontré esto:

```
package com.minhap.Util;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AutowireHelper implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private AutowireHelper() {
    }

    public static void autowire(Object classToAutowire) {
        AutowireHelper.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(classToAutowire);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AutowireHelper.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

No deja de ser una clase Helper para injectar beans.
En la clase Listener llamaremos al método que se encargará de hacer la inyección (**autowired()**):

```
@PostUpdate
    public void onUpdate(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    AutowireHelper.autowire(this);
                    System.out.println("Update User :" + user.getName());
                    ReportAudit reportAudit = new ReportAudit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), "INFO", "Admin", "update in User", "OK", "OK");
                    reportAuditService.addReportAuditInfo(reportAudit);
                }
    }
```

Y con esto resolví el error.