# CRUD SPRING BOOT. No guarda en tabla

Tags: spring-boot, crud

Buenas a todos,

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Tengo mi CRUD de Spring para hacer la persistencia en mi BBDD Oracle sql.

A continuación os detallo:

Clase **Listener** que controlará las **transacciones** en BBDD:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.PostPersist;
import javax.persistence.PostRemove;
import javax.persistence.PostUpdate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import com.minhap.Util.AutowireHelper;
import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;
import com.minhap.model.User;
import com.minhap.service.ReportAuditService;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ReportAuditCtrl {
    @Autowired
    private ReportAuditService reportAuditService;

    @PostUpdate
    public void onUpdate(Object object) {
        if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    AutowireHelper.autowire(this);
                    System.out.println("Update User :" + user.getName());
                    ReportAudit reportAudit = new ReportAudit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), "INFO", "Admin", "update in User", "OK", "OK");
                    reportAuditService.addReportAudit(reportAudit);
                }
    }   

    @PostPersist
    public void onPersist(Object object) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterCommit() {
                if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    AutowireHelper.autowire(this);
                    System.out.println("Insert User :" + user.getName());   
                    ReportAudit reportAudit = new ReportAudit(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), "INFO", "Admin", "update in User", "OK", "OK");
                    reportAuditService.addReportAudit(reportAudit);
                }
            }

        });
    }  

    @PostRemove
    public void onRemove(Object object) {
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void afterCommit() {
                if(object instanceof User) {
                    User user = (User)object;
                    System.out.println("Remove User :" + user.getName());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public ReportAuditService getReportAuditService() {
        return reportAuditService;
    }

    public void setReportAuditService(ReportAuditService reportAuditService) {
        this.reportAuditService = reportAuditService;
    }
}
```

**Interfaz del Service**

```
import java.util.List;
import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;
public interface ReportAuditService {

    ReportAudit addReportAudit(final ReportAudit reportAudit);
    List<ReportAudit>getAllReportAudit();
    ReportAudit getReportAuditById(final Long id);

}
```

**Service que implementa la interfaz**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.minhap.dao.ReportAuditRepository;
import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;

@Service
public class ReportAuditServiceImpl implements ReportAuditService {

    @Inject
    private ReportAuditRepository reportAuditRepository;

    @Override
    public ReportAudit addReportAudit(ReportAudit reportAudit) {

        return reportAuditRepository.save(reportAudit);
    }

    public ReportAuditRepository getReportAuditRepository() {
        return reportAuditRepository;
    }

    public void setReportAuditRepository(ReportAuditRepository reportAuditRepository) {
        this.reportAuditRepository = reportAuditRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ReportAudit> getAllReportAudit() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ReportAudit getReportAuditById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Repository**

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.minhap.model.ReportAudit;

@Repository("reportAuditRepository")
public interface ReportAuditRepository extends CrudRepository<ReportAudit, Long> {
}
```

La clase **Entity**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT_AUDIT")
public class ReportAudit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ", allocationSize = 20, name = "REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    private Timestamp fx_event;
    private String tipo;
    private String actor;
    private String description;
    private String event_result;
    private String extrainfo;

    public ReportAudit() {
        super();
    }

    public ReportAudit(Timestamp fx_event, String tipo, String actor, String description, String event_result,
            String extrainfo) {
        this.fx_event = fx_event;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.actor = actor;
        this.description = description;
        this.event_result = event_result;
        this.extrainfo = extrainfo;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getFx_event() {
        return fx_event;
    }

    public void setFx_event(Timestamp fx_event) {
        this.fx_event = fx_event;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(String actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEvent_result() {
        return event_result;
    }

    public void setEvent_result(String event_result) {
        this.event_result = event_result;
    }

    public String getExtrainfo() {
        return extrainfo;
    }

    public void setExtrainfo(String extrainfo) {
        this.extrainfo = extrainfo;
    }



}
```

En el la clase Listener hago uso del Service para llamar al método que me hará el insert en BBDD. Como podréis ver la clave primaria de la entidad se auto-genera con una secuencia que previamente cree en mi BBDD. La tabla igual esta creada. A continuación adjunto los script de dichos objetos:

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT_AUDIT (
  id                 INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fx_event           TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  tipo               VARCHAR2(20),
  actor              VARCHAR2(500),
  description        VARCHAR2(500),
  event_result       VARCHAR2(500),
  extrainfo          VARCHAR2(500),
  CONSTRAINT reports_audit_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE REPORT_AUDIT_SEQ START WITH 1;
```

El problema es que no me inserta en la tabla, pero tampoco me da ningún en error en la consola de servidor. (Tengo habilitado trazas de logs)

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Para que entiendan un poco lo de la clase listener os adjunto otros post que creé hace dos días:
[java.lang.NullPointerException al llamar a Service desde clase Listener](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/131657/java-lang-nullpointerexception-al-llamar-a-service-desde-clase-listener)

Comment: No da error pero no hace nada... has probado a debugar para asegurarte de que el código se está ejecutando? O a añadir trazas con un logger...

Comment: Si. Llego hasta el repository perfectamente. He probado a meterle trazas y llega perfectamente.

Comment: Me da que tiene que ser alguna notacion en la clase entidad que pueda faltarme pero ... no doy con ello.

Comment: Encontré la misma [pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639131/is-it-possible-to-persist-new-entities-in-a-pre-postpersist-listener), pero no acabo de entender la solución...

Comment: Lo mismo me pasa a mi jejeje. Seguiré investigando.

Comment: Tengo mi duda de si es posible lo que quieres hacer, si los métodos `@Post...` se llaman cuando la transacción se ha cerrado, es posible que se ignore cualquier intento de inserción/actualización posterior

Comment: Yo diría que si pues la modificación previa del usuario la hace y automaticamente después salta el evento PostUpdate y recojo el usuario que se ha modificado inclusive.

Comment: Alguna idea? Necesito esto para poder hacer auditoria de las entidades que sufren un cambio, para guardar una serie de info del cambio en una tabla.